# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'), and multiple API requests in React.js

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, map-function, get-request

I know this map reading error has been asked *a lot* here before and I looked at several closed issues, but since their causes were different from mine I've opted to open a new topic. At the moment I'm facing 2 errors, so let me tackle each at a time.

**What I want to accomplish:**
After submitting a search query, the "Results" component should be rendered and make a `GET` request to my back-end (which, in turn, will make a `GET` request to the external API and send back the results to React). Once it fetches the data it should store it in the `details` variable, which will be mapped and rendered in a child component.

**First problem:**

Despite a successful request is being made to my back-end and also to the external API - which I could check by using `console.log` -, it seems like the retrieved data isn't being stored inside the variable, resulting in an undefined array to be mapped. So, what am I doing wrong here? Is this happening because the component is trying to map the array before the `GET` request completes and executes the `setDetails(response.data)` even though it comes way below in the code?

```
function Results() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(location.state.search);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

  axios.get("http://localhost:5000/results/" + query).then((response) => {
    setDetails(response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
  });

  const results = details.total_results;
  const pages = details.total_pages;
  const baseURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154";

  return (
    <Container>
      <Card sx={{ padding: 3, margin: 2 }}>
        <CardContent>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography variant="h5">Results</Typography>
              <Typography>{results ? results : 0} results found</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <List sx={{ mt: 5 }}>
                {details.results.map((result) => {
                  return (
                    <ResultItem
                      key={result.id}
                      imgURL={baseURL + result.poster_path}
                      title={result.title}
                      year={result.release_date}
                      director=""
                      synopsis={result.overview}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </List>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </CardContent>
        <Pagination
          count={pages}
          onChange={(event, page) => {
            history.push("/results" + query + "&page=" + page);
            setQuery(query + "&page=" + page);
          }}
        />
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Results;
```

**Second problem:**

I'm not sure exactly why, but the `GET` request is triggering **two** responses from the external API instead of just one. Both, front and back-end, are logging the retrieved data two times, and I suspect the multiple requests are coming from my front-end, causing the back-end to trigger multiple requests as well. And that is a huge step from a previous error when something in my code was triggering an infinite loop of requests.

I'll probably have issues with the pagination later on as well, I guess, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue One

Initial `details` state is an array, not an object with a `results` array property.

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
```

so attempting to map `details.results` results in the error "cannot read property X of undefined.

To resolve, use valid initial `details` state that matches how it's used later. It should be an object with a valid `results` array property.

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState({ results: [] });
```

## Issue Two

You are invoking the axios request right in the body of the function component, as an unintentional side-effect. This is likely the result of rendering your app into a `React.StrictMode` component which double-invokes certain lifecycle methods and functions as a way to [detect unexpected side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects), the function body being one of them.

You should move this into an `useEffect` hook with the `query` as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:5000/results/" + query)
    .then((response) => {
      setDetails(response.data);
    });
}, [query]);
```